# Order by positive/negative values and any other post not found in a table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select, sql-order-by

So i'm trying to get all posts from the database and order them but i'm stuck.
I want to order the posts by most liked -> not liked -> most unliked.

The problem is that some posts appear in the `wti_like_post` table and some dont. So I'm not sure how to order them, normally I would use something like `ORDER BY lp.value DESC`

here is my query:

```
 $querystr = "SELECT DISTINCT {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_excerpt, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.guid, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_author
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}wti_like_post lp ON lp.post_id = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID
            WHERE t.term_id = " . $_SESSION['pageCategory'] . " 
            AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post' 
            AND post_status = 'publish' 
            ORDER BY (lp.value <= 0) DESC, ({$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID != lp.post_id) DESC, (lp.value > 0) DESC
            LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset
            ";
```

So far I have tried solutions I found on S.O  but nothing seems to work.

One of the solutions I tried suggested using someting like `ORDER BY (lp.value <= 0) DESC, ({$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID != lp.post_id) DESC, (lp.value > 0) DESC` but it does not work.

I will also mention that alot of the posts I would like to get are not linked to the `wti_like_post` table.

Here is a screenshot of the wti_like_post table, which links liked/disliked posts to the wordpress posts table in the database.

[image]

Any ideas on how I might approach this problem.

Cheers

Comment: Be aware that `LEFT JOIN t... WHERE t=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN t` - and there's no point LEFT JOINing tables from which you select no columns

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem in SQLite (I know you did not tag, just as a debugging and demonstration tool), the `.dump` of that toy database makes most of a great MCVE conveniently.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the advice. The join is required as I want to get the posts which are associated with a specific category.

Comment: That would be an INNER JOIN

Comment: Ok so If I'm not selecting anything from those tables I use INNER JOIN, and if I'm selecting from those tables I use LEFT JOIN. and I would use `INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id`

Answer (score 1):

To

> order by most liked -> not liked -> most unliked

you should `ORDER BY lp.value DESC`

Comment: this orders them in this order. most liked -> most unliked -> not liked